# TF update slow, Sychronize laptop request time with ROS update time

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-melodic, tf2, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently My TF package update extremely slow.
Error pops up for "Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time xxxxx but the latest data is at time yyyyyyy."           WaitforTransform does not work.

How should I sychronize my laptop time with the ROS time on the robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340564/tf-update-slow,-sychronize-laptop-request-time-with-ros-update-time/) by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-23**:
Could you please tell us what you have already tried / found?

There are many, many Q&As on this site about this exact subject. To find them, use Google (append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query).

It would be great if we could avoid creating yet more duplicate questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. You need to synchronize the time on your laptop with the platform you are using.

---

Originally posted by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) with karma: 56 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0